# Could I use an if else statement here?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm building a trivia game, and it has a game finished screen that displays how well you did. It says `"You got __ out of __ right"` (ex: 6 out of 8 right) and the code looks like this:

```
function displayThankyou() {
  $(".screen").hide();
  $("#thankyou-screen").show();
  $("#game-results").html(
    `You got ${trivia.totalCorrect} of ${trivia.totalAnswered} correct.`
  );
}
```

If I wanted to show a different message if the person did well on the game, like 6 right or better: "You did great!" or if they didn't do well, 5 right or less: "Better luck next time.", do I use an if else to do this?

Comment: You could. You could also use an array of different messages, and the number right would be the index into the array.

Comment: Try it first....then if you run into problems ask question showing what you tried. SO isn't really a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 1):

@Chad Roussel, yes, you could use an 'if-else' statement for this. For example (pure JS):

```js
//initialise variables correct and total
var correct = trivia.totalCorrect;
var total = trivia.totalAnswered;

//if statement
if (correct >= 6){
     //log to user their "greatness."
     console.log("You did great!");
}else{
     console.log("You didn't get a 6/8. Try again");
}
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp for more info on if-else statements!

EDIT:
As mentioned by others, you could use a switch-case solution. However, I find no benefit of one versus the other. Do what works for you!